# Memcache and memcached: "getaddrinfo failed"

Tags: php, memcached, xampp

I have installed memcache and memcached in XAMPP in OSX Mountain Lion. Though non of them appear in `phpinfo()`.

At the top of my *`index.php`* file I simply include the file:

```
include 'memcache.php'
```

Then when I enter my website I get a MEMCACHE INFO page that gives me this error:

> Error message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

What am I doing wrong?

Can memcache and memcached be installed without showing up in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Do I have to start memcached some how or is it started when i start apache in xampp? Completely new to this. Where do I configure things like hostname?

Comment: There is no `memcache.php` for the PHP extension. Are you using someone's memcached PHP library? You still need memcached installed and the PHP memcache/memcached libs.

Comment: I've installed both memcache and memcached using multiple tutorials but non of them appear in phpinfo nor `php -m` in the terminal

Comment: Okay, so I will try to be more blunt: **the correct memcached server name is not specified somewhere**. This error has *nothing* to do with the memcached daemon; it has to do with the client *not being able to resolve an IP address* - if it can't do this, it can't connect to the memcached server even if it *was* running. (So please stop with the other nonsense and *focus on the actual error message*.)

Comment: Then where should I specify the memcached server name?

Comment: @Oskwish Who knows - likely some nonsense inside "memcache.php" (so RTFS), hopefully in a variable at the top - FWIW see http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php

Comment: I went into the memcache.php file and checked and changed the `$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[]` to `'127.0.0.1:11211'`. Now when I include the memcache.php file on my index page I get some diagrams and tables with stats. Though when I try to do something like `$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);` I get a error on the stats page that says: `Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it my following [this guide.](http://m-schmidt.eu/tag/memcached/)
Seems like memcache wasn't completely installed or something because now it appears in `phpinfo()` and everything is working! Don't know why it wasn't working when following several other tutorials though a theory is that it installed memcache for the built-in apache in OSX.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a memcache or memcached daemon running and listening on.   Memcache(d) is just like a separate server process like apache.  It listens at a port / socket for requests.  If you don't have one running, you can't connect to it.  If one is running, you probably got the connection details wrong... It's sort of like your DSN string for access to a database through mysqli or PDO.

I'm guessing inside the 'memcache.php' file your including, it's asking to set a hostname or nodename.   This also tells me you should be trying to connect to a memcached server (as memcached has the concept of nodes).  Open it up and find where it's trying to connect to the memcache server and edit it to point to localhost or whatever your machine name is (or ip address).

Comment: This is **not** the problem... or at least not the current one.  The error clearly shows that this is a name resolution problem.

Comment: And how do I run one? Where do I find the correct connection details?

Comment: @Oskwish `memcached` on your terminal.

Comment: @Oskwish if you don't know if memcache is running, you might have 2 issues.  One the name resolution that Brad mentions as well as no server running.

Comment: @Brad That gave me `failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use`

Comment: @Oskwish, Then memcached is already running... or something else on that part, but unlikely.

Comment: .. the error doesn't say *"server is not running"* it says *"I can't even try to connect because the address is incorrect, missing, or otherwise non-resolvable"*

Comment: @Oskwish also, if memcache is running on your machine, connect to it with the memcache php library, not the memcached php library.  The same applies if memcached is running on your machine, connect to it with the php memcached library (though I think the older memcache lib can connect to memcached server).

Comment: @Oskwish see my update--open the memcache.php file and look to see if there is a place to set your hostname or nodename

Comment: People all over the internet seem to say different things about what memcache is and what memcached is. Where can I find the memcached php library that I should include?

Comment: @Oskwish I agree, the first time playing with memcache(d) is overwhelming... it doesn't help to have 2 separate flavors with very similar names.

Comment: @Oskwish there's no include file that will 'make it work'.  PHP has static library modules to connect, but it's like connecting to a mysql db server, you need to specify the hostname, port, etc... for the connection before you query (or in this case store things in the memory cache).  I'd run a php -m at the command line and make sure you see the memcached module listed.  Then, start looking at the memcache.php file you're including and see how it's trying to connect.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the hostname you have provided for connecting to memcached is incorrect.  Your error is essentially that DNS cannot find the hostname.

Comment: @Oskwish, That depends on where you're running it!  If you're running it on `localhost`, then your hostname is `localhost`.

Comment: But im just including the `memcache.php` file and I'm getting the error. Where should I enter my hostname?

Comment: @Oskwish, Obviously, that's your problem.  We have no idea what memcache class you're using, so if you could fill in that detail, perhaps we could suggest where to configure it.

Comment: @Brad I think you onto the correct thing with the name not being specified, but because it mentions 'node name' I'm pretty sure the memcache.php library he's using is trying to hit a memcached server.  I'm not sure Oskwish fully sees how memcache(d) is supposed to work--this is probably his first stab at it.